# Can't fill nan values in pandas even with inplace flag

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pandas dataframe containing NaN values for some column.
I'm trying to fill them with a default value (30), but it doesn't work.

Original dataframe:

```
                  type               avg_speed  

0                 CAR                     32.0  
1                 CAR                      NaN  
2                 CAR                      NaN  
3                 BIKE                    16.2  
4                 CAR                     28.5  
5                 SCOOTER                 29.7  
6                 CAR                     30.7  
7                 CAR                      NaN  
8                 BIKE                     NaN  
9                 BIKE                    35.1
...
```

Desired result:

```
                  type               avg_speed  

0                 CAR                     32.0  
1                 CAR                       30  
2                 CAR                       30  
3                 BIKE                    16.2  
4                 CAR                     28.5  
5                 SCOOTER                 29.7  
6                 CAR                     30.7  
7                 CAR                       30  
8                 BIKE                      30  
9                 BIKE                    35.1
```

My code:

```
def fill_with_default(pandas_df, column_name, default_value):
    print(f"Total count: {pandas_df.count()}")
    print(f"Count of Nan BEFORE: {pandas_df[column_name].isna().sum()}")

    pandas_df[column_name].fillna(default_value, inplace=True)

    print(f"Count of Nan AFTER: {pandas_df[column_name].isna().sum()}")

    return pandas_df

df = fill_with_default(df, "avg_speed", 30)
```

Output:

```
Total count: 105018
Count of Nan BEFORE: 49514
Count of Nan AFTER: 49514
```

The chain of dataframe transformations and list of columns are too long, so it's difficult to show all steps (join with another dataframe, drop useless columns, add usefull columns, join with other dataframes, filter etc.)

I've tried other options but they also don't work:

```
#pandas_df.fillna({column_name: default_value}, inplace=True)
#pandas_df.loc[pandas_df[column_name].isnull(),column_name] = default_value
...
```

Type of column before applying "fillna" is fload64, the same as default_value

Therefore, my question is: what could be the potential reasons of this problem?
What kind of transformation can lead to this problem? Because this is the method that works for another similar data frame. The only difference between them lies in the chain of transformations.

BTW, there is a system log at this place:

```
/home/hadoop/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/pandas/core/generic.py:6287: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: 
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a- 
copy
self._update_inplace(new_data)
```

Comment: Would you mind giving us a part of your dataframe and the desired output?

Comment: The code you have should work, the only thing I can think of is that you are passing NaN for your default_value. Can you provide a small reproducible example?

Comment: @Akavall The default value is not Nan, I have its value in the print command, just reduced here stuff like this and other debug prints...

Comment: This code really should work, I ran it localy and - aside from the missing `)` on the first print line of the code, its solid. I am also not sure what the problem is here....

Comment: your code works on my machine as desired too.

Comment: perhaps do this `pandas_df[column_name] = pandas_df[column_name].fillna(default_value)`? Certainly even if this works, we can't explain why `inplace=True` can't do the same in your machine.

Comment: What kind of transformation can lead to this? I don't understand how it is technically possible? It works with another dataframe...